# Regex Operation Results Are Saved in Variables But They Show Up Multiple Times

Tags: azure-cli

In the script that someone posted for splitting a string on a delimiter which I'm using as the basis of my script, I can see that the delimiter is a semicolon and the end results are two separate strings. I tried to use this same script to break my string into two pieces by setting the whitespaces as the delimiter or the spot where the string needs to break. After setting whitespaces as the delimiter it works but the resulting strings show up multiple times instead of once in each variable. Below is my script

```
Input="secretname    value"

names=$(echo $Input | tr "[[:space:]]*" "\n")

for name in $names
do
 
    secret="$name"
    value="$name"
    echo $secret
    echo $value
done
```

Comment: They are printing twice because you have two `echo` statements that both end up printing `$name`

Answer (score 0):

What I wanted to do was split the string on the delimiter resulting in two separate strings then save the resulting strings to two different variables. However, it looks like the script I initially found doesn't lend itself to easily allow the saving of the resulting strings to separate variables. Below is the script that does exactly what I needed:

```
var="JDoe,jdoe@email.com"
name=$(cut -d"," -f1 <<< "$var")
email=$(cut -d"," -f2 <<< "$var")
name="$name" 
email="$email"
echo $name
echo $email
--------------------------------------
Output
JDoe
jdoe@email.com
```